# hadoop storage directory not pointing correctly

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

While i am trying to configure hadoop single node cluster,i have actually given the namenode and datanode directory as **/home/hduser/data/namenode,/home/hduser/datanode,** but while i am trying to format namenode and trying to start the cluster for the first time,namenode storage directory is pointing to **/tmp directory** only not my actual storage path /home/hduser/data/namenode, i have not configured any '/tmp' directory also,can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not defined anything in core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml, then it will use  /tmp/hadoop-*nameofyourhadoopuser.

Please define tmp directory location in core-site.xml and then it will use your path which you have provided in hdfs-site.xml.

Plz make sure you should have proper permission on above paths.

Comment: its actually formatting the cluster like  '/tmp/hadoop-*nameofyourhadoopuser' only as you mentioned above,but actually i have defined namenode and datanode dir path in hdfs-site.xml but not defined any 'dfs.tmp.dir' still its formatting in tmp only.

Comment: you will have to specifically mentioned tmp property in core -site.xml to pick your paths

Comment: i have configured hdfs-site.xml like below,<configuration>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/data/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/data/datanode</value>
     </property>
</configuration> and configured dfs.tmp.dir as '/home/hduser/tmp ' also but still its formatting like same tmp location only...

Answer (score 0):

in hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/data/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/data/datanode</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Make sure both path should be correct.

remove other properties from core-site.xml and paste give property

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i have configured like above but still namenode is not formatting in the above mentioned namenode path ,its picking '/tmp/hadoop-*nameofyourhadoopuser' only ,due to this namenode and data node process  not all getting started properly...

Comment: i think hadoop using default-core-site.xml. try updated ans